# Force DirectX application to redraw

Tags: directx, hook

Any one know how we can force a DirectX application to refresh(repaint)? I am trying to hook into DirectX draw functions, but don't know how to refresh the drawing to intercept the api call.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of application? Most DX applications have a loop that redraws the scene all the time.

Answer (score 0):

When to "repaint" is determined entirely by the application - there is no convention for when to do so.  Assuming it is rendering using a swap chain, your best bet is to wait until the application calls `Present` on its own, then intercept API calls until the next `Present`.